# Flow Type error: property of unknown type. This type is incompatible with array type

Tags: javascript, reactjs, flowtype

I have the following JSX. Something like:

```
{
  event.divisions &&
  event.divisions.edges &&
  (event.divisions.edges: Array<Object>)
    .map(d => d.node)
    .map(division => (
      <div>{division}</div>
    ))
}
```

Without casting it tells me that it's missing an annotation. With casting I get the following error:

```
 81:    (event.divisions.edges: Array<Object>)
         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ property `edges` of unknown type. This type is incompatible with
 81:    (event.divisions.edges: Array<Object>)
                                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^ array type
```

How could that be incompatible? And how could it be unknown? I explicitly told it the type.

Comment: Do you want to loop over the keys of object event.divisions.edges

Comment: Casts in Flow are safe. It will still verify that the type you give it is correct. There's no way to solve your problem without knowing where `event` comes from and what its type is.

Answer (score 0):

You can map over the array of object in the followig fashion

```
{
  event.divisions &&
  event.divisions.edges &&
  event.divisions.edges.map(d => {
      return d.node.map(division => (
      <div>{division}</div>
    ))
   }

}
```

Comment: Doing that get's me a different flow error, though.


     "81:                           event.divisions.edges
                                    ^ call of method `map`. Method cannot be called on
     81:                           event.divisions.edges
                                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ property `edges` of unknown type"

Comment: So if I don't add a cast, flow warns me that edges is unknown. If I do add a cast, flow gives me an error that it is incompatible.

Comment: how are you getting the value i.e event.divisions.edges

Answer (score 0):

Try doing this instead:

```
{
  event.divisions &&
  event.divisions.edges &&
  (event.divisions.edges: $ReadOnlyArray<Object>)
    .map(d => d.node)
    .map(division => (
      <div>{division}</div>
    ))
}
```

Comment: Same issue... :-(